# How to use Pageable in Jpa

Tags: java, spring, datatables, spring-data-jpa

I want to do paging in jpa, java, Datatables.js

My Controller is

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/notice_selectList.do")
public Map<String, Object> notice_selectList(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @PageableDefault Pageable pageable) throws Exception{

    Map<String, Object> paramMap = RequestUtil.getParameterMap(request);
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    int length = Integer.parseInt((String) paramMap.get("length"));     //한페이지당 보여줄 글 갯수
    int start  = Integer.parseInt((String) paramMap.get("start"));      //시작페이지 

    int pageLength = (length == 0)?20:length;       
    int startPage = (start == 0)?1:start + 1;

    List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<Sort.Order>();
    orders.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "noticeNo"));
    Sort sort = Sort.by(orders);

    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(startPage, pageLength, sort);

    Page<Notice> noticeList = repository.findAll(pageRequest);

    //------------- dataTables에 맞게 키값 세팅
    //--------------data:데이터
    //--------------recordsTotal,recordsFiltered:갯수 및 페이징
    resultMap.put("data"            , noticeList.getContent());
    resultMap.put("recordsTotal"    , noticeList.getTotalElements());
    resultMap.put("recordsFiltered" , noticeList.getTotalElements());

    return resultMap;
}
```

My Repository is

```
public interface NoticeRepository extends JpaRepository<Notice, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Banner>{
    public Page<Notice> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

first Page is correctly view,

```
 select*
 from NOTICE
 order by NOTICE_NO desc 
limit 0, 20
```

but if I click the second page, 
result is

```
 select*
 from NOTICE
 order by NOTICE_NO desc 
limit 400, 20
```

and click the third page,

```
 select*
 from NOTICE
 order by NOTICE_NO desc 
limit 800, 20
```

Why does this result?

Comment: What are the values for `paramMap.get("start")`?

Comment: maybe something wrong with the front end.

Comment: paramMap.get("length")  is  "The number of pages  I want to show on one page" /  paramMap.get("start") is "Starting point of the page"

Comment: and what are the values you have written there?

Comment: they written, if push the first page, length = 20, start = 0 / second page length = 20 / start = 21

Answer (score 0):

First I would debug what the parameters length and start contain. If it is not 20 or 40 and paraMap does contain these values, I would look into my Request going over the Network (Dev Tools in your Browser). If it sends the right values and start is still wrong, post the URL Path, I assume it is a POST Request, and lets have a look in there.

If the values are indeed 200 or 400 in your Request, have a look on your calling frontend, maybe some String Concantation or if you use Struts, Form Parsing problems. A common mistake is using the value and index of a combobox or somethink like that. If you search in your Frontend, use the Browser Devtools to debug the Request or Form, put Breakpoints in your Model and try to pinpoint where the values switch to the high numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ll try it again !